# How to do the product of arrays of an array in Python

Tags: python, numpy

In a single line, how can I get the product of the arrays of an array?
I need it to be done for multi columns cases

2 columns example:

```
X = [[1 4]
     [2 3]
     [0 2]
     [1 5]
     [3 1]
     [3 6]]

sol = [4 6 0 5 3 18]
```

4 columns example:

```
X = [[1 4 2 3]
     [2 3 1 5]
     [0 2 3 4]
     [1 5 2 2]
     [3 1 1 6]
     [3 6 3 1]]

sol = [24 30 0 20 18 54]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a row-wise multiplication. You can perform this with:

```
X.prod(axis=1)
```

for example:

```
>>> X
array([[1, 4],
       [2, 3],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 5],
       [3, 1],
       [3, 6]])
>>> a.prod(axis=1)
array([ 4,  6,  0,  5,  3, 18])
```

Comment: I don't understand the 'Note'

Comment: @Joracosu: sorry, I was talking about your second example. It is not a 4d array, it is a 2d array with four columns in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use numpy.multiply.reduce

```
np.multiply.reduce(x, axis=1)
```